# Maui Blazor Hybrid - Cannot double click on the exe in the bin folder

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I recently installed the preview version of visual studio and created a new .net maui blazor hybrid app.

When debugging the app, a window shows up and everything works just as expected.
However when i go to the bin folder and run the exe that is located there the window does not come up.
In the windows event logs i can see the following:

Exception Info: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies

And indeed that dll is missing from the bin folder.

What does visual studio do to make this work? How can i just run the exe?

Comment: To make a "deployable" app, see [Publish .Net Maui app for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/overview). HOWEVER, that uses [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/tool-overview) - the resulting .exe, when run, does an INSTALLATION. Is that ok? AFAIK, there isn't currently a supported way to make a Maui exe run immediately, without performing an installation. Perhaps an MSBuild expert can figure out how to replicate what VS does. The challenge will be wrapping that up into something you can move to another pc.

Comment: Or maybe you just need all the dependencies. Use [Fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to find them all. With luck, you could make a zip file that could be moved to another pc.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yeah, I'm guessing you're right and currently the only way to run it without visual studio starting up would be to actually install it. It's just the first time for me that an exe in the bin folder doesn't actually work on its own. So I was wondering how that works exactly.

Comment: Good question. It could be as simple as VS knowing where the dependencies are, and executing it with a command path variable that includes such location(s). Then DLL load would search the folders in given path. I'm sure it also uses some assemblies in PC's GAC - but those should be found automatically when you double-click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now we only support so-called “packaged” apps. Those you need to publish to an MSIX and install in order to run.

We’re working on adding the unpackaged scenario as well, you can track that here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3166

While searching for the above issue I noticed a couple of others ones though. According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7789) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6202) it might already be possible right now, you might want to try!