# MAUI application only runs in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, maui

I am using MAUI with .NET 7.0 in visual studio. I created an example project selected the nuget manager and ran the example code. This works totally fine. If I go into debug/bin/win and click the executable the program does not run. Even though it works completly fine if I press play run in visual studio.

When I move all code to a visual studio code project and creating my own launch. When i run it it gives an exeption, which probably all related. The exception is (file App.g.i.cs line 28):

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Gui.dll: 'Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)'`

An important DLL for MAUI is missing, however i could not fix it by setting:

`<SelfContained> or <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>`

Also the DLL is no where to be found. My guess is visual studio some how gives the executable access to the dll. But when i click the .exe from the bin or run the project with vscode it does not have access to this dll.

How could i fix this? Does anyone know how visual studio gives executables access to dlls when running it in the id?

Comment: You can't launch the exe (yet). Did you search to see if anyone else had this problem, before posting your question? [Maui - Cannot double click on the exe in the bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549856/maui-blazor-hybrid-cannot-double-click-on-the-exe-in-the-bin-folder)

Answer (score 1):

**Just enable nonpackage publishing**:

Go to Solution Explorer and click on your project to access XAML file of your project.

Inside `<PropertyGroup>` put `<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>`, then rebuild the project.

Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/GgU4ulGYQEk?t=70) how to do this, see after 01:10

Boom, You are done, now you can run your app from build folder (using .exe file) and spread this build as usual app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a MSIX package by publishing your app ,and there is two ways to do it by vs or by CLI , here is the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-cli)
by following the documentation you will be able to creat MSIX package in the Release folder (not the debugg folder) .

Comment: I already tried publishing the app and that works, but i need the excutable. However my problem rather is i want to run build and debug the project in vscode and there I am missing the dll and maybe also other things Visual Studio gives when running it in the IDE.