# How to execute Blazor build output directly when publishing a MAUI Blazor Hybrid project

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

When working with WinForms or WPF, one can simply open the bin/Debug folder and execute a .exe to run the app. No need to install anything. This is useful for a simplified debugging process on different platforms when studying a new version, for example.

However, with Blazor for desktop development, is has been a hassle to get it working liek that. It is necessary to install from the .msi file after publishing. Simply building it is not enough.

It seems to be impossible to execute it, even from the command line using dotnet from Powershell.

Is this intentional? Is there any workaround to it?

Attempted commands on Powershell:

```
dotnet run --project ./
dotnet run .
dotnet run
dotnet run --project ./blazorbuildtest.exe
dotnet run --project ./blazorbuildtest.dll
./blazorbuildtest.exe
```

For example, when executing ./blazorbuildtest.exe, it throws:

./blazorbuildtest.exe

Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '' threw an exception.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WinRT.ActivationFactory`1' threw an exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Classe n▒o registrada (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode) at WinRT.BaseActivationFactory..ctor(String typeNamespace, String typeFullName) at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1..ctor()
at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1..cctor() End of inner exception stack trace --- at WinRT.ActivationFactory`1.ActivateInstanceI
at Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.WindowsAppRuntime.DeploymentInitializeOptions..ctor()
at Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.WindowsAppRuntime.DeploymentManagerCS.AutoInitialize.get_Options() in C:\Users\lrspe.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.3.230724000\include\DeploymentManagerAutoInitializer.cs:line 44
at Microsoft.Windows.ApplicationModel.WindowsAppRuntime.DeploymentManagerCS.AutoInitialize.AccessWindowsAppSDK() in C:\Users\lrspe.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.3.230724000\include\DeploymentManagerAutoInitializer.cs:line 30
at .cctor()
End of inner exception stack trace ---

It was expected to get the app running without installation, just like it is possible with WPF and WinForms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maui Blazor Hybrid - Cannot double click on the exe in the bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549856/maui-blazor-hybrid-cannot-double-click-on-the-exe-in-the-bin-folder)