# Maui App will run through Visual Studio but not via exe

Tags: c#, maui

I am developing a maui app in VS 2022, Debug and Release will run fine when launched via VS.

However, when I go to the apps bin folder, it will not launch, I click on the `.exe` and nothing happens.

I tried copying the bin/release and debug folders to another Win10 machine, same issue. I published a msix and tried that route and it will not run.

How do I make it run without VS?

Event viewer shows this error:

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '' threw an exception.
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WinRT.ActivationFactory`1' threw an exception.
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

I cannot figure out why it works launching in VS but not running .exe directly on same machine, let alone a different machine.

Comment: Run ProcessMonitor while you quickly start up the app from exe and VisualStudio  (quickly capturing small traces) and compare the log outputs. Probably best to start comparing the registry differences first then file diffs. Can you confirm if are you running as Admin in VS and if you ticked the Register for COM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maui Blazor Hybrid - Cannot double click on the exe in the bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549856/maui-blazor-hybrid-cannot-double-click-on-the-exe-in-the-bin-folder)

Comment: @Rob, that does not help, as mentioned, I did package the app and tried on different systems, all with the same error.

Comment: You can't run the exe of a packaged app directly. You need to install the package and run from (for example) start menu. If you want a runnable exe you need to build unpackaged. Full explanation and links in the previous thread.